# Does SQLAlchemy start DB transaction in session?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

My problem is that I open a transaction using the context manager on the AsyncSession object in SQLAlchemy. I make a simple query, then use another client to change the read value, and then read it again inside the transaction.

My expectation was that I would read the same value in both cases. At least that's how I thought the transactions worked. The isolation level was set to "REPEATABLE READ".

It's important to mention that I did the operations over ProxySQL. If I connected to the MySQL DB directly, the transaction behaved as expected: first read: value X. Update from another client to value Y. Second read in the transaction: value X.

As a result of this, I read the MySQL logs. I found that SQLAlchemy never sends `BEGIN;` to MySQL, it just sets `SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;` and sends `COMMIT;` after a series of commands, is there any way for SQLAlchemy to send `BEGIN;` to the DB when the transaction starts? Or is it problem of ProxySQL-SQLAlchemy misconfiguration?

### Engine Setup

```py
engine = create_async_engine(
    f"mysql+aiomysql://{user}:{password}@{host}:{port}{db_string}?charset=utf8mb4",
    echo=False,
    pool_pre_ping=True,
    isolation_level="REPEATABLE READ",
    poolclass=AsyncAdaptedQueuePool,
)

session = async_scoped_session(
    async_sessionmaker(engine, expire_on_commit=False),
    scopefunc=asyncio.current_task,
)
```

### Code (not a DB transaction)

```py
async with session.begin() as transaction:
    # Right here `user`.`money` is 10.
    cursor = await transaction.session.execute(text("SELECT `user`.`money` FROM `user` WHERE `user`.`id` = 398"))
    res = cursor.fetchall()
    
    print("RES:", res)
    # RES: [(10,)]

    # In this 15 second sleep window I used another client and changed `user`.`money` to 20.
    await asyncio.sleep(15)

    cursor = await transaction.session.execute(text("SELECT `user`.`money` FROM `user` WHERE `user`.`id` = 398"))
    res = cursor.fetchall()
    
    print("RES2:", res)
    # RES2: [(20,)]
```

### Code (DB transaction)

If we add explicit "BEGIN" execute, it will work as supposed.

```py
async with session.begin() as transaction:
    await transaction.session.execute(text("BEGIN"))

    # Right here `user`.`money` is 10.
    cursor = await transaction.session.execute(text("SELECT `user`.`money` FROM `user` WHERE `user`.`id` = 398"))
    res = cursor.fetchall()
    
    print("RES:", res)
    # RES: [(10,)]

    # In this 15 second sleep window I used another client and changed `user`.`money` to 20.
    await asyncio.sleep(15)

    cursor = await transaction.session.execute(text("SELECT `user`.`money` FROM `user` WHERE `user`.`id` = 398"))
    res = cursor.fetchall()
    
    print("RES2:", res)
    # RES2: [(10,)]
```

Comment: I tried this concept using asyncpg while following the sqlalchemy docs and it seems to work but it differs in a few ways from your setup.  Where does `AsyncAdaptedQueuePool` come from ?

Comment: Also what version of SQLAlchemy are you using ?

Comment: @IanWilson:
I'm using SQLAlchemy==2.0.15 and `AsyncAdaptedQueuePool` comes from `sqlalchemy.pool` package. Problem occurs even if I removed `poolclass` argument. I also tried it on SQLAlchemy==1.4 non-async way and result was the same. Have you looked at the db logs? Does SQLAlchemy do the `BEGIN;` command in your case?

Comment: Yes it does.  The SQLAlchemy docs say the driver you use in your question, aiomysql,  is out of date, can you try a different driver?  What version of mysql are you using?  Maybe I can test it later.  I only have postgresql running natively I have to run mysql in a docker container.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a complete answer because this is for postgresql but I will include the code.

```py
import sys
import asyncio

from sqlalchemy import MetaData, select

from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase, mapped_column, Mapped
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncAttrs, async_sessionmaker, AsyncSession, create_async_engine


meta = MetaData()


class Base(AsyncAttrs, DeclarativeBase):
    pass

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    name: Mapped[str]

async def insert_objects(async_session: async_sessionmaker[AsyncSession]) -> None:
    async with async_session() as session:
        async with session.begin():
            session.add_all([User(name="test1"), User(name="test2")])


async def update_objects(async_session: async_sessionmaker[AsyncSession]) -> None:
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    async with async_session() as session:
        async with session.begin():
            user = (await session.scalars(select(User).where(User.id == 1))).first()
            user.name = "new test"

async def select_objects(async_session: async_sessionmaker[AsyncSession]) -> None:
    async with async_session() as session:
        async with session.begin():
            usernames = (await session.scalars(select(User.__table__.c.name))).all()
            for username in usernames:
                print (username)
            await asyncio.sleep(5)
            usernames = (await session.scalars(select(User.__table__.c.name))).all()
            for username in usernames:
                print (username)


def get_engine():
    username, password, db = sys.argv[1:4]
    return create_async_engine(
        f"postgresql+asyncpg://{username}:{password}@/{db}",
        echo=True,
        pool_pre_ping=True,
        isolation_level="REPEATABLE READ",
    )


async def async_main() -> None:

    engine = get_engine()

    async_session = async_sessionmaker(engine, expire_on_commit=False)

    async with engine.begin() as conn:
        await conn.run_sync(Base.metadata.create_all)

    await insert_objects(async_session)

    await asyncio.gather(
        update_objects(async_session),
        select_objects(async_session),
    )

    # for AsyncEngine created in function scope, close and
    # clean-up pooled connections
    await engine.dispose()


asyncio.run(async_main())
```

### With READABLE :

```
DROP DATABASE
CREATE DATABASE
2023-06-07 14:27:00,834 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine select pg_catalog.version()
2023-06-07 14:27:00,834 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [raw sql] ()
2023-06-07 14:27:00,836 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine select current_schema()
2023-06-07 14:27:00,836 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [raw sql] ()
2023-06-07 14:27:00,837 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine show standard_conforming_strings
2023-06-07 14:27:00,837 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [raw sql] ()
2023-06-07 14:27:00,838 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2023-06-07 14:27:00,843 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT pg_catalog.pg_class.relname 
FROM pg_catalog.pg_class JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace ON pg_catalog.pg_namespace.oid = pg_catalog.pg_class.relnamespace 
WHERE pg_catalog.pg_class.relname = $1::VARCHAR AND pg_catalog.pg_class.relkind = ANY (ARRAY[$2::VARCHAR, $3::VARCHAR, $4::VARCHAR, $5::VARCHAR, $6::VARCHAR]) AND pg_catalog.pg_table_is_visible(pg_catalog.pg_class.oid) AND pg_catalog.pg_namespace.nspname != $7::VARCHAR
2023-06-07 14:27:00,844 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00026s] ('users', 'r', 'p', 'f', 'v', 'm', 'pg_catalog')
2023-06-07 14:27:00,847 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine 
CREATE TABLE users (
    id SERIAL NOT NULL, 
    name VARCHAR NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)


2023-06-07 14:27:00,848 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [no key 0.00014s] ()
2023-06-07 14:27:00,915 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine COMMIT
2023-06-07 14:27:00,951 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2023-06-07 14:27:00,958 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine INSERT INTO users (name) SELECT p0::VARCHAR FROM (VALUES ($1::VARCHAR, 0), ($2::VARCHAR, 1)) AS imp_sen(p0, sen_counter) ORDER BY sen_counter RETURNING users.id, users.id AS id__1
2023-06-07 14:27:00,958 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00036s (insertmanyvalues) 1/1 (ordered)] ('test1', 'test2')
2023-06-07 14:27:00,964 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine COMMIT
2023-06-07 14:27:00,996 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2023-06-07 14:27:00,997 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT users.name 
FROM users
2023-06-07 14:27:00,998 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00054s] ()
test1
test2
2023-06-07 14:27:03,013 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2023-06-07 14:27:03,018 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT users.id, users.name 
FROM users 
WHERE users.id = $1::INTEGER
2023-06-07 14:27:03,018 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00067s] (1,)
2023-06-07 14:27:03,028 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine UPDATE users SET name=$1::VARCHAR WHERE users.id = $2::INTEGER
2023-06-07 14:27:03,028 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00061s] ('new test', 1)
2023-06-07 14:27:03,031 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine COMMIT
2023-06-07 14:27:06,004 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT users.name 
FROM users
2023-06-07 14:27:06,005 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [cached since 5.008s ago] ()
test1
test2
2023-06-07 14:27:06,007 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine COMMIT
```

### With READABLE commented out:

```py
#isolation_level="REPEATABLE READ",
```

```
DROP DATABASE
CREATE DATABASE
2023-06-07 14:27:44,947 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine select pg_catalog.version()
2023-06-07 14:27:44,947 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [raw sql] ()
2023-06-07 14:27:44,949 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine select current_schema()
2023-06-07 14:27:44,949 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [raw sql] ()
2023-06-07 14:27:44,950 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine show standard_conforming_strings
2023-06-07 14:27:44,950 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [raw sql] ()
2023-06-07 14:27:44,951 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2023-06-07 14:27:44,956 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT pg_catalog.pg_class.relname 
FROM pg_catalog.pg_class JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace ON pg_catalog.pg_namespace.oid = pg_catalog.pg_class.relnamespace 
WHERE pg_catalog.pg_class.relname = $1::VARCHAR AND pg_catalog.pg_class.relkind = ANY (ARRAY[$2::VARCHAR, $3::VARCHAR, $4::VARCHAR, $5::VARCHAR, $6::VARCHAR]) AND pg_catalog.pg_table_is_visible(pg_catalog.pg_class.oid) AND pg_catalog.pg_namespace.nspname != $7::VARCHAR
2023-06-07 14:27:44,957 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00031s] ('users', 'r', 'p', 'f', 'v', 'm', 'pg_catalog')
2023-06-07 14:27:44,960 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine 
CREATE TABLE users (
    id SERIAL NOT NULL, 
    name VARCHAR NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)


2023-06-07 14:27:44,960 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [no key 0.00016s] ()
2023-06-07 14:27:45,036 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine COMMIT
2023-06-07 14:27:45,068 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2023-06-07 14:27:45,071 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine INSERT INTO users (name) SELECT p0::VARCHAR FROM (VALUES ($1::VARCHAR, 0), ($2::VARCHAR, 1)) AS imp_sen(p0, sen_counter) ORDER BY sen_counter RETURNING users.id, users.id AS id__1
2023-06-07 14:27:45,071 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00016s (insertmanyvalues) 1/1 (ordered)] ('test1', 'test2')
2023-06-07 14:27:45,074 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine COMMIT
2023-06-07 14:27:45,096 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2023-06-07 14:27:45,097 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT users.name 
FROM users
2023-06-07 14:27:45,097 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00025s] ()
test1
test2
2023-06-07 14:27:47,116 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2023-06-07 14:27:47,121 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT users.id, users.name 
FROM users 
WHERE users.id = $1::INTEGER
2023-06-07 14:27:47,121 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00069s] (1,)
2023-06-07 14:27:47,130 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine UPDATE users SET name=$1::VARCHAR WHERE users.id = $2::INTEGER
2023-06-07 14:27:47,131 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00064s] ('new test', 1)
2023-06-07 14:27:47,133 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine COMMIT
2023-06-07 14:27:50,104 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT users.name 
FROM users
2023-06-07 14:27:50,104 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [cached since 5.007s ago] ()
test2
new test
2023-06-07 14:27:50,106 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine COMMIT
```